# How to I make a variable available to a function without passing it or using a global, or should I take a different approach?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a function to fix the float precision problem in rust (among other languages). I need to choose to `.floor()` or `.ceil()` within the function based on the passed parameter. Whats the best way to approach this problem. If something other than a function serves the propose better, by all means! Thank you for your help!

```
fn main() {
    to_round(7.987, "floor");
}

fn to_round(n: f64, floor_or_ceil: &str) -> f64 {
    fn test(diff_n: f64) -> f64 {
        if floor_or_ceil == "floor" {
           diff_n.floor()
        } else {
           diff_n.ceil()
        }
    }
    test(n)
}
```

Comment: Instead of what you don't want to do (parameter or global), what *do* you want to do? How do you want to pass in the value if not by global state or a parameter? And why does neither of those work for you?

Comment: Having your config set as global almost always proves to be a bad design choice, preventing refactorings (mutable configs, modularity, etc.). If you have a config, pass it down as argument to where it's needed.

Comment: a global is excessive and I dont want to pass floor_or_ceil to test() multiple times through out to_round() if it can be avoided... Im just looking for something more elegant that hopefully will lvl up my skill

Comment: @DenysSéguret can you think of anything more elegant?

Answer (score 6):

If you replace your inner `fn` function with a *closure*, then the code you have will compile. Closures can refer to variables from the enclosing scope, whereas `fn`s cannot.

```rust
fn main() {
    to_round(7.987, "floor");
}

fn to_round(n: f64, floor_or_ceil: &str) -> f64 {
    let test = |diff_n: f64| -> f64 {
        if floor_or_ceil == "floor" {
           diff_n.floor()
        } else {
           diff_n.ceil()
        }
    };
    test(n)
}
```

However, closures do come with some caveats; in particular, they can't be generic functions, and can't be used where function pointers can be (unless they don't mention ("close over") any variables from the enclosing scope and are merely using closure syntax instead of `fn` syntax).

The most general-purpose clean solution to this class of problem is to explicitly pass the needed parameters, *but* you can minimize the clutter of it by such means as using a struct (especially if there is more than one value needed) and making the functions methods of that struct:

```rust
fn main() {
    let c = MathContext { rounding_mode: "floor" };

    c.to_round(7.987);
}

struct MathContext {
    rounding_mode: &'static str,  // Side note: this should really be an enum, not a string

    // And you can add more fields here for any other parameters needed.
}

impl MathContext {
    fn to_round(&self, n: f64) -> f64 {
        self.test(n)
    }

    fn test(&self, diff_n: f64) -> f64 {
        if self.rounding_mode == "floor" {
           diff_n.floor()
        } else {
           diff_n.ceil()
        }
    }
}
```

Whether exactly this set of methods fits depends on what you're actually doing; if `test` is very specific to `to_round` then it doesn't make sense to pull it out this way. But it seems likely that this pattern might be useful elsewhere in your code, at least, if you're doing things like picking which way to round numbers.

Comment: Note: closures that don't capture local variables can be coerced into function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should eliminate the use of `&str`s as enums. Just declare an enum:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Round {
    Floor,
    Ceil,
}

use ::Round::{Floor, Ceil};

fn round(n: f64, setting: Round) -> f64 {
    match setting {
        Floor => n.floor(),
        Ceil => n.ceil(),
    }
}
```

The second variant is using closures.

```rust
fn round_func(setting: Round) -> impl Fn(f64) -> f64 {
    move |n| match setting {
        Floor => n.floor(),
        Ceil => n.ceil(),
    }
}
```

This will take as input your setting and return a closure that will calculate either the floor or ceiling for you. EG you could do something like

```rust
let closure = round_func(setting);
println!("{}", closure(5.5));
println!("{}", closure(5.5));
```

This will take as input the configuration and return a closure that serves as a function.

In this particular case, we can actually do even better by directly returning a function pointer. The code looks like this:

```rust
fn round_func_pointer(setting: Round) -> fn(f64) -> f64 {
    match setting {
        Floor => f64::floor,
        Ceil => f64::ceil,
    }
}
```

The code could also be written

```rust
fn round_func_pointer(setting: Round) -> fn(f64) -> f64 {
    match setting {
        Floor => |n| n.floor(),
        Ceil => |n| n.ceil(),
    }
}
```

This works because the "closure" `|n| n.floor()` actually doesn't capture anything at all (no `move` keyword necessary), and therefore is compiled to a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Class variable w/ precision and rounding mode

Rust doesn't have syntax for declaring a field in a struct as static like C++, Java, and other languages. However, it is still possible to declare a static variable that for all intents and purposes is a "class variable".

In the implementation below, the scope of the static variable `CONFIG` is restricted to the file it's declared in; so, in that sense it isn't a "global" variable. The struct declared within the same file has exclusive access to it, and all instances of that struct access the same variable.

To ensure that the "class variable" doesn't get clobbered by simultaneous writes from separate threads, `RwLock` is used to synchronize it. This incurs a small cost in performance over implementations that don't synchronize access in single-threaded environments.

The `lazy_static` macro sets up the "class variable" to delay initialization until the variable is actually needed at runtime.

```
use std::sync::RwLock;

#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    // The tuple holds (rounding-mode, precision).
    static ref CONFIG: RwLock<(RoundMode, u32)> = {
        RwLock::new((RoundMode::Auto, 3))
    };
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum RoundMode { Ceil, Floor, Auto }
```

The struct implementation below provides a way for client code to set the rounding mode (Auto, Ceil, and Floor) and precision (number of decimal positions to round to) for all instances of `HasValue`.

```
pub struct HasValue { value: f64 }

impl HasValue {
    pub fn new(value: f64) -> Self
    {
        HasValue { value }
    }
    pub fn config() -> (RoundMode, u32)
    {
        *CONFIG.read().unwrap()
    }
    pub fn set_config(mode: RoundMode, precision: u32)
    {
        *CONFIG.write().unwrap() = (mode, precision);
    }
    pub fn round(&self) -> f64
    {
        use RoundMode::*;
        
        let (mode, prec) = HasValue::config();
        let base = 10_f64.powf(prec as f64);
        
        match mode {
            Auto  => (self.value * base).round() / base,
            Ceil  => (self.value * base).ceil()  / base,
            Floor => (self.value * base).floor() / base,
        }
    }
}
```

Creating, configuring, printing...

```
fn main() 
{
    let v = HasValue::new(7.98555);
    let r = v.round();
    println!("r={:?}", r);
    
    HasValue::set_config(RoundMode::Floor, 4);
    let r = v.round();
    println!("r={:?}", r);
}
```